# SMTP NDR problems

Tags: exchange-2003

When my users add an email item as an attachment the mail does not send and produces an NDR. it works fine for all other attachments. I am currently using Exchange 2003. I think it may be corrupting when trying to send out as SMTP. funny thing is it will delivery the same mail locally to each individual. Anyone have any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Would you care to share the NDR? Or at least give us the SMTP status code?

Comment: Attached are my SMTP logs. It looks like the usernames are being stripped by my SMTP.

Comment: here is another one

Comment: - OutboundConnectionCommand [10/Mar/2011:14:05:36 -0800] "EHLO -?AMLG1.amlg.americanmlg.net SMTP" 0 4 - OutboundConnectionResponse [10/Mar/2011:14:05:36 -0800] "- -?250-mx.google.com at your service,  SMTP" 0 51 - OutboundConnectionCommand [10/Mar/2011:14:05:36 -0800] "QUIT - SMTP" 0 4 - OutboundConnectionResponse [10/Mar/2011:14:05:36 -0800] "- -?221 2.0.0 closing connection o41si8691477yhm.57 SMTP" 0 47

Comment: - OutboundConnectionResponse "- -?220 as49.bis.na.blackberry.com ESMTP SMTP" 0 36
 - OutboundConnectionCommand  "EHLO -?AMLG1.amlg.americanmlg.net SMTP" 0 4
 - OutboundConnectionResponse [10/Mar/2011:14:06:24 -0800] "- -?250-as49.bis.na.blackberry.com SMTP" 0 30
 - OutboundConnectionCommand [10/Mar/2011:14:06:24 -0800] "QUIT - SMTP" 0 4
 - OutboundConnectionResponse [10/Mar/2011:14:06:24 -0800] "- -?221 as49.bis.na.blackberry.com SMTP" 0 30
 - OutboundConnectionResponse [10/Mar/2011:14:06:36 -0800] "- -?220 mx.google.com ESMTP c9si15483744ybn.82 SMTP" 0 42

Comment: @Bill it would be really helpful if you edited your question with these logs, then they will be easier to read.

Comment: @Bill also, a copy of the NDR users get would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. I moved my database a while ago due to a bad HDD and did not change the working directory. I went into regedit and changed the location of where the working directory was located and now it is working again.